# Cannot type after login with Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: keyboard, 17.10

I recently installed Ubuntu 17.10 after migrating from Mint. After I enter my login password, I am unable to type at all using my keyboard, or even using a virtual keyboard. I initially was able to type until I opened the settings panel, but I haven't been able to type at all since. I have tried using both Wayland and Xorg and haven't had any luck with either. Has anybody else run into this, or know how to fix this? I have a feeling a reinstall will be required so that I can type anything, but I've reinstalled before and this issue has persisted.

Comment: I should add that disabling slow keys fixed the virtual keyboard, but my main one is still useless.

Comment: Do specify your hardware

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem between some Logitech keyboards and fwupd https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fwupd/+bug/1717340. I used `sudo apt remove fwupd` typed with a virtual keyboard to get rid of it and my keyboard worked after a restart. I also had an issue with the virtual keyboard where the shift button wasn't working, so I had to use the special characters map to enter my password.